# SQL Server query is not working - why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I try to execute a query from SQL Server 2012, it is not executing and I get this error:

[image]

We tried :

1. Restarting the SQL Server service
2. Ping to the Remote SQL Server

Both did not work for us.

Any help on it would be much appreciated!

Comment: This link might be helpful.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149539/the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available

Comment: Thanks. i will go through the link

Comment: Added Hosts file entry for  database server. and Checked ODBC connection it is working well. But trying to connect from SSMS.EXE   throwing same error.